# Can my girlfriend go to Canada on a visitor Visa while waiting for a working holiday visa?

Tags: canada, uk-citizens, working-holiday-visas

My girlfriend is British and has has entered the visa pool (she waits to be picked to apply, then will have to submit her application). She wants to come with me, but we have to wait until she is picked to apply for the working holiday visa, then once she is picked we have to wait for the visa application process. Is it possible for her to come with me on a tourist visa/visitor visa until she is picked from the pool for the working holiday? If she is picked while in Canada, does she have to go back to England in order to apply or can she apply from within Canada while on a tourist visa? Or does anyone know any other way we can go about all this?